# Make row clickable jQuery datatable, also hidden rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html table stuffed with data that is sorted by the awesome plugin datatables. Now I wan't each row to be clickable, so I added the following piece of jquery:

```
$( document).ready( function() {
        $('.clickable').click(function () {
            $(location).attr('href', $(this).data("href"));
        })
    }
);
```

This only works however, for the piece of the table that is initially shown (so the first 10 rows). If I extend the number of entries that are show with the default button: [image], my new entries are not clickable. How do I load the javascript in such a way, that also new entries are clickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try to use the handler for table row click as written below :

```
$('body').on('click', '.clickable tbody tr', function () {
```

As @Michael pointed out always try use separate function for Event Handling as its easy maintain and modify.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript that makes rows clickable is run once when the page first loads. It would be better to make it a separate function that gets called immediately after any new rows from the table load.

As @Prakash Thete pointed out, using .on('click') instead of click should add the effect to dynamically added elements, even when called once.